# Is there an event in Powerpoint when the window is minimized maximized or changed in size?

Tags: c#, events, window, vsto, powerpoint

Is there an event in Powerpoint when the window is minimizedm maximized or changed in size? I need to do some operation when the active Powerpoint window is maximized or the size is changed.

Additional Note:
The need for this is, i have 3 monitors with different resolutions in extended mode,
so when i drag my Powerpoint application from one monitor to another and place it, this size change event should fire, so i can change the size of the taskpane based on monitor resolution size.

Comment: No, PowerPoint has no such events. You might need to look into using the Windows API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternative, Though i can't find the minimize/maximize etc, i at least have an event which fires when the size of the window is changed.

Just use the SizeChanged Event inside the UserControl which was binded to the CustomTaskPane you created in Powerpoint.

```
this.SizeChanged += Event_SizeChanged;
private void Event_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Your code here
}
```